# Надо ли заключать в кавычки слова?

Tags: кавычки

Надо ли заключать слова *Архыз*, *Ведучи* и *Роза Хутор* (курорты) в кавычки?

«*Ведучи сейчас идет по пути Архыза в Карачаево-Черкесии — пилотного курорта в рамках туркластера.*»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В обычном тексте не нужно. Но если постановку кавычек требуют другие правила в контексте (прямая речь, например), тогда нужно, конечно.

**Upd**. Поскольку в вопрос был добавлен контекст, перенесу в ответ свой комментарий:

Для кавычек никаких оснований нет, если речь идёт о названиях населённых пунктов. Если же в селе Архыз есть санаторий "Архыз", например, — это совсем другое дело. Но насколько я понимаю, в данном случае речь идёт всё же о населённых пунктах.

Comment: Ведучи сейчас идет по пути Архыза в Карачаево-Черкесии - пилотного курорта в рамках туркластера. В этом предложении не нужны кавычки?

Comment: @НатальяКоролева Для кавычек никаких оснований нет, если речь идёт о названиях населённых пунктов. Если же в селе Архыз есть санаторий "Архыз", например, — это совсем другое дело.